# Issue with HTML module after upgradation from DNN version 4.9.5 to DNN version 6.1.2

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-imc

If I upgraded from DNN version 4.4 to version 4.9.5 and then to version 6.1.2 then it gives me the error

> Error: Buying is currently unavailable.
>   DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: The type
>   initializer for 'DotNetNuke.Modules.Html.DataProvider' threw an
>   exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'DotNetNuke.Modules.Html.DataProvider' threw an
>   exception. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of
>   type 'DotNetNuke.Modules.HTML.SqlDataProvider' to type
>   'DotNetNuke.Modules.Html.DataProvider'. at
>   DotNetNuke.Modules.Html.DataProvider.CreateProvider() at
>   DotNetNuke.Modules.Html.DataProvider..cctor() --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace --- at
>   DotNetNuke.Modules.Html.DataProvider.Instance() at
>   DotNetNuke.Modules.Html.WorkflowStateController.GetWorkflows(Int32
>   PortalID) at
>   DotNetNuke.Modules.Html.HtmlTextController.GetWorkflow(Int32 ModuleId,
>   Int32 TabId, Int32 PortalId) at
>   DotNetNuke.Modules.Html.HtmlModule.OnInit(EventArgs e) --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---

For HTML module only

Comment: i think you have to manually replace your DotNetNuke.Modules.Html.DataProvider bundle with the one available in DNN 6.1.2
Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

Like Devjosh said, it appears your HTML module was incorrectly installed.  You will need to replace the DotNetNuke.Modules.Html.dll file in your DotNetNuke installation's "bin" folder.  If you can login to the site, you can also try re-installing the module by going to the Host > Extensions page, clicking the "Available Extensions" tab, expanding the "Modules" section, then clicking the "Install" button next to the HTML module.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking in the App_Code folder, if you still have an HTML module folder in there, delete it.

Check your BIN folder for DLLs that have HTML in the name, there should only be one I believe, called dotnetnuke.modules.html.dll